# C++ most vexing vector element swap

Tags: c++

I stumbled into this problem while working on a small project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> v;
    for (int x = 1; x < 6; ++x)
    {
        int * a = new int(x);
        v.push_back(a);
    }

    unsigned int y = 4;
    for (auto a : v)
    {
        std::cout << "BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = " << *v[0] << ", v[1] = " << *v[1] << ", v[2] = " << *v[2] << ", v[3] = " << *v[3] << ", v[4] = " << *v[4] << std::endl;
        std::swap(a, v[y]);
        std::cout << "AFTER SWAP: v[0] = " << *v[0] << ", v[1] = " << *v[1] << ", v[2] = " << *v[2] << ", v[3] = " << *v[3] << ", v[4] = " << *v[4] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "==========" << std::endl;
        --y;
    }

    // for (std::vector<int*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    // {
    //     std::cout << "BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = " << *v[0] << ", v[1] = " << *v[1] << ", v[2] = " << *v[2] << ", v[3] = " << *v[3] << ", v[4] = " << *v[4] << std::endl;
    //     std::swap(*it, v[y]);
    //     std::cout << "AFTER SWAP: v[0] = " << *v[0] << ", v[1] = " << *v[1] << ", v[2] = " << *v[2] << ", v[3] = " << *v[3] << ", v[4] = " << *v[4] << std::endl;
    //     std::cout << "==========" << std::endl;
    //     --y;
    // }

    // inb4 "You forgot to deallocate!" This is an example.
}
```

At the end of the code, there are two loops which do the exact same task but in a different fashion.

The for loop with `auto` keyword produces this result with missing numbers:

```
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 5
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 1
==========
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 1
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
==========
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
==========
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
==========
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
==========
```

The for loop with iterator works as expected:

```
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 5
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 5, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 1
==========
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 5, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 1
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 5, v[1] = 4, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
==========
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 5, v[1] = 4, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 5, v[1] = 4, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
==========
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 5, v[1] = 4, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 2, v[4] = 1
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 5, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 1
==========
BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = 5, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 1
AFTER SWAP: v[0] = 1, v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[3] = 4, v[4] = 5
==========
```

What is going on with the `auto` loop? Why do I lose values?

Here's a CPP.SH link to see for yourselves: http://cpp.sh/2ve3

Comment: Just alike Abhishek said, in the iterator alternative `it` is logically a reference to the vector element, but `auto a` is just a copy. Try `auto & a` and it should work as expected.

Comment: @enobayram It works. I was always under the impression that `auto a` in this case are references already.

Comment: note also that the most vexing parse problem in `C++` relates to something totally different.

Comment: The actual type of `auto` is deduced just like the template arguments in a generic function. The exact rules are quite complex but, you should keep in mind that they won't deduce a reference unless explicitly told to. You can imagine how much more dangerous it would have been otherwise.

Comment: *"inb4 "You forgot to deallocate!" This is an example."*. Your example would still expose your problem with `std::vector<int> v;` without the leak. And `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;` would produce compile time error at the place of the missing reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with  `for(auto a : v)`
you actually get a copy of the value, not the in place value in the array.
You need to specify that you actually want the reference to it by declaring the loop as `for(auto&a : v)`

Functioning example:

```
for (auto& a : v)
{
    std::cout << "BEFORE SWAP: v[0] = " << *v[0] << ", v[1] = " << *v[1] << ", v[2] = " << *v[2] << ", v[3] = " << *v[3] << ", v[4] = " << *v[4] << std::endl;
    std::swap(a, v[y]);
    std::cout << "AFTER SWAP: v[0] = " << *v[0] << ", v[1] = " << *v[1] << ", v[2] = " << *v[2] << ", v[3] = " << *v[3] << ", v[4] = " << *v[4] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==========" << std::endl;
    --y;
}
```

if you try to trace the execution of your program now that you know that it was a value instead of a reference, you'll find out that the result makes sense.

Now that you understood how it works, you can just use the standard library to achieve what you try to do in just one call:

```
std::reverse(myvector.begin(),myvector.end());
```

Example at:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/?kw=reverse

Comment: I will mark this as correct, since I cannot mark comments made by @enobayram as such. Also, vector reversal was not my objective; you can remove it if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Here copy of your array's  value is stored in to variable "a". a is not the reference to ur array's value .that's why when you swap two variables it is swapped but in variable a .Not in the actual value of array. And as ur another parameter of swap is array's value it is taking value of variable a. That's why u r not getting desired output. 
The statement of auto a:v is actually statement as shown below:

```
a=v[0];
a=v[1]; (on next iteration)
```

And so on .
As you can see a is having just copy of array's value not reference. That's why you're getting this kind of output .